# Getting a background image to span several div elements

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I am designing a website based of this template https://templated.co/linear. The css that defines the content containers with different backgrounds looks like this:

```
#main
{
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.homepage #content
{
    text-align: center;
}

.homepage #content header h2
{
}

#sidebar h2
{
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0.50em;
}

#featured
{
    position: relative;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
}

#featured h3
{
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#featured .pennant
{
    font-size: 4em;
}

#featured .button
{
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

I have a svg file with a pattern and a transparent background I would like to display on top of those colors, but spanning the containers without interruption. The way I have been trying to define the following in css:

```
#spots
{
    background-image: url(../images/spots.svg) !important;
}
```

and then in html:

```
    <div id="spots">
        <div id="main">
            Text
        </div>
        <div id="featured">
            More Text
        </div>
    </div>
```

However the background colors of the containers that the svg is supposed to sit on top of, overrides the background image of the spots tags despite the !important flag. How would I go about getting the pattern configured the way I have described above?

Comment: So the background image of the wrapper has to be on top of the inner elements...right?

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be affected by the breaks between inner elements.

Comment: Huh...how is this supposed to look? Like this? http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/kXpprL This will obscure the content though.

Comment: Like this https://imgur.com/a/NsDC0?

Comment: That's of very little use frankly What does the end design look like...not a wireframe?

Comment: I am trying to get the dolphins between the text and the background of the  elements.

Comment: Oh....You'd have to set the image as a background to all three divs, layer in a single color gradient as a second background image to the inner divs...so far so easy...problem is, you'd have to line up all the background images...that's **hard**....and not responsive I'd imagine.

Comment: I am dealing with a single image that contains the entire pattern, so I am not that concerned about alignment.

Comment: Or do you mean aligning the background color for the content divs?

Comment: But you'd have to put the bg image on each and every div...then line all the background images up...with a pattern that might be hard....but until we have the pattern we can't help much more. Try it...it's not simple.

Comment: So in other words, there is no way for the divs, to show their background colors, a continuous background image on top of that, and then text on top of that?

Comment: It's *possible*...but pretty hard....that's what I'm saying...but without the intended pattern you plan on using it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Here is a mock-up of the pattern. https://imgur.com/a/kNevH

Comment: See the problem - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/kXpprL

Comment: Yes, which is why I was trying to set the background image once, and then lay the text divs around it.

Comment: So it would be fair to say, that it is possible to get a website looking the way I want, but the second you add a paragraph, you have to do it all over again?

Comment: Yep...that's probably true.